# MediaPlayer with on/off switch

Tags: android

I'm unable to get MediaPlayer to function with an on/off button.

I instantiate the MediaPlayer and the mute button:

```
music = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.loop);
music.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
ibVolume = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_volume);
ibVolume.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mute);
ibVolume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (music.isPlaying() && (music != null)) {
            music.stop();
            music.release();
            ibVolume.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volumeon);
            return;
        }
        if (!music.isPlaying() && (music != null)) {
            ibVolume.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mute);
            music.start();
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

It only works for 1 iteration. Turns sound on, then off, then it's dead. What can I do? I've been through about 20 MediaPlayer tuts. I've loaded it off the main thread, on whatever.....IT DOESN'T work :(

Answer (score 1):

OK. Just needed to reinstantiate the MediaPlayer after release. Why doesn't stop() stop?

Answer (score 0):

remove the line.

```
music.release();
```

after music.stop();

then it should work.

Comment: Without release() it don't stop.

Comment: Actually release is unnecessary. Re-instantiating isn't

Comment: try calling pause() and then stop()

Comment: pause() is the answer. why don't they get into this more on the developer site?

Comment: its there on the developer page.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#pause%28%29

Comment: And while you're at it friends :) How to I handle the lifecycle? WHY CAN'T I find a good resource?

Comment: I've read that page like 50x. I still have no idea how to use it.

Comment: If you don't handle the sound in onPause(), it keeps playing. Should I handle only handle  it in onDestroy() as they suggest?

Comment: If you want the sound to be played in background, handle in onDestroy. if you dont want the music when app is in background, handle it in onPause().